# How to handle variable in Batch script nested loop?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, environment-variables

the following batch work well until the comment "the following do not perform as expected" I've try any kind of %; %%, ! around the variables but always fail, either do not have any thing or errors!

```
rem @ECHO OFF
ECHO %~dp0
ECHO %~dpnx0
SET fileNameForWMIC=
SET "7ZAEXE=7za.exe"
SET "SOURCE=C:\Program Files (x86)\my prog\PFM\*.*"
SET "LOCATION=C:\Program Files (x86)\my prog\PFM"
SET "TARGET=PFM.7z"
SET "REFFILE=NEWPFM.7z"
SET "IMPFILE=verPFM.txt"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET 7ZAEXE=%~dp0!7ZAEXE!
ECHO !7ZAEXE!
SET TARGET=%~dp0!TARGET!
ECHO !TARGET!
SET REFFILE=%~dp0!REFFILE!
ECHO !REFFILE!
SET IMPFILE=%~dp0!IMPFILE!
ECHO !IMPFILE!
rem "!7ZAEXE!" a "!TARGET!" @"!IMPFILE!" 
rem the whole directory
rem for /D %%X in ("!SOURCE!") do  !7ZAEXE! a "!TARGET!" "%%X"
rem only the important files listed in text file
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN ("%IMPFILE%") DO ( 
  echo %%G version %%H
  SET fileNameForWMIC=%%G 
  SET GoodVer=%%H
  SET "fileNameForWMIC=!fileNameForWMIC:\=\\!"
  ECHO !fileNameForWMIC!
  ECHO Goodver !GoodVer!
  rem the following do not perform as expected
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %%I IN (`wmic datafile where Name^="!fileNameForWMIC!" get Version ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) DO (
    SET "filever1=%%~I"
    ECHO( !filever1!
  )
  IF /I NOT ["!filever1!"] == ["%GoodVer%"] (
    ECHO "%fileNameForWMIC%" have version^=!filever1! instead of %GoodVer%
    "!7ZAEXE!" a "!TARGET!" "%fileNameForWMIC%"
    SET /A NbError+=1  
  ) ELSE ( "!7ZAEXE!" e "!REFFILE!" -o!LOCATION! "%fileNameForWMIC%" -r)
)
```

here are some lines of verPFM.txt

```
Name                                               Version
c:\program files (x86)\my prog\pfm\intl.dll,0.18.1.0
c:\program files (x86)\my prog\pfm\libeay32.dll,1.0.1.16
c:\program files (x86)\my prog\pfm\libl1sa.dll,1.2.0.1
```

At first it read correctly file name and version located in the verpfm.txt file, but the second For/F fail to get fileNameForWMIC variable so the reste can not be complete.

The batch file is located in a directory where I put also the 7za.exe to compress and the verPFM.txt file.

The NewPFM.7z contain the file listed in verPFM.txt, the purpose of the batch is to check that all files listed in verPFM.txt and located in "LOCATION" have the same version as listed, if not same the file in LOCATION in the archive PFM.7z and replace it with the one in NewPFM.7z

I hoppe to build the final batch with a reverse option to restore the file saved in PFM.7z

How to fix this??  1000 thanks in advance

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: It's what I'm trying to do, that why the batch is full of ECHO

Comment: Why are you doing this `SET "fileNameForWMIC=!fileNameForWMIC:\=\\!"`? This line is adding double backslashes to the path.

Comment: doubling backslashes to the path is required to be recognized by WMIC command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after trying many different way I got this batch using procedure.

It work as expected

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO %~dp0
ECHO %~dpnx0
SET fileNameForWMIC=
SET "ZAEXE=7za.exe"
SET ZAEXE=%~dp0%ZAEXE%
IF NOT EXIST %ZAEXE% (
 ECHO 7za.exe is missing please fix it and restart
 GOTO :END
 )
SET DEST="C:\Program Files (x86)\My Prog\PFM"
IF /I "%1"=="/revert" GOTO :REVERT
SET "IMPFILE=verPFM.txt"
SET IMPFILE=%~dp0%IMPFILE%
IF NOT EXIST %IMPFILE% (
  ECHO verPFM.txt is missing please fix it and restart
  GOTO :END
  )
SET "REFFILE=refPFM.7z"
SET REFFILE=%~dp0%REFFILE%
IF NOT EXIST %REFFILE% (
  ECHO refPFM.7z is missing please fix it and restart
  GOTO :END
  )
SET "SOURCE=C:\Program Files (x86)\My Prog\*.*"
SET "TARGET=PFM_ALL.7z"
SET TARGET=%~dp0%TARGET%
rem the whole directory
FOR /D %%X IN ("%SOURCE%") do  %ZAEXE% a "%TARGET%" "%%X"
IF NOT EXIST %TARGET% (
  ECHO PFM_ALL.7z was not created please report
  GOTO :END
  ) ELSE ECHO A complete backup of %SOURCE% is in %TARGET%
  rem change target file
  SET "TARGET=PFM.7z"
  SET TARGET=%~dp0%TARGET%
  SET /A NbError=0
  rem "!7ZAEXE!" a "!TARGET!" @"!IMPFILE!" 
  rem only the important files listed in text file
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN ("%IMPFILE%") DO ( 
    rem echo %%G version %%H
    SET fileNameForWMIC=%%G 
    SET GoodVer=%%H
    SET "fileNameForWMIC=!fileNameForWMIC:\=\\!"
    rem ECHO !fileNameForWMIC!
    rem ECHO Goodver !GoodVer!
    call :process "%%G" %%H
    )
  goto :next  
:next
IF %NbError% EQU 0 (
  ECHO All files was already upto date
  GOTO :END
  ) ELSE ( 
    IF NOT EXIST %TARGET% (
      ECHO PFM.7z was not created please report
      GOTO :END
      ) ELSE ( ECHO %NbError% files saved in %TARGET% )
  )   
:END
  SET SOURCE=
  SET TARGET=
  SET fileNameForWMIC=
  SET fileNameForW=
  SET GoodV=
  SET GoodVer=
  SET NbError=
  SET REFFILE=
  SET DEST=
  SET filename=
  EXIT /B 
:process
  SET fileNameForW=%1 
  rem ECHO %fileNameForW%
  SET GoodV=%2
  SET fileNameForW=%fileNameForW:\=\\%
  rem ECHO %fileNameForW%
  rem ECHO Goodv %GoodV%
  SET fileNameForWW=%1 
  rem ECHO %fileNameForWW%
  FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %%I IN (`wmic datafile where Name^=%fileNameForW% get Version ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) DO (
  SET "filever1=%%~I"
  rem ECHO( !filever1!
  )
  IF /I NOT ["!filever1!"] == ["%GoodV%"] (
    ECHO %fileNameForW% have version^=%filever1% instead of %GoodV%
    "%ZAEXE%" a "%TARGET%" %fileNameForWW%
    SET /A NbError+=1  
    rem ECHO %fileNameForWW%
    call :getfilename %fileNameForWW%
    "%ZAEXE%" e "%REFFILE%" -o%DEST% !filename! -aoa
    GOTO :EOF
    ) ELSE ( 
    GOTO :EOF
    )
 :getfilename
  SET filename=%~nx1
  rem echo The name of the file is %filename%
  rem set folder=%~dp1
  rem echo It's path is %folder%
  GOTO :EOF
:REVERT
  rem change target file
  SET "TARGET=PFM.7z"
  SET TARGET=%~dp0%TARGET%
  IF NOT EXIST %TARGET% (
   ECHO PFM.7z not found could not revert
   GOTO :END
   ) ELSE (
    "%ZAEXE%" e "%TARGET%" -o%DEST% * -aoa
    GOTO :END
    )
```

procedure :END finish the batch by cleaning the variable first

procedure :REVERT undo the change made, it's involved by calling the batch.cmd /revert

the IMPFILE is created using the same wmic command as the one use inside to get the file version, with the /OUTPUT, then the file is edited to remove blanc character and converted from UTF16 into ASCII (using notepad++) if not the file can not be read !